# three.jsのBufferGeometryで定義した頂点をvertexShaderに渡したが、何も表示されない

Tags: three.js, shader, glsl

three.jsのBufferGeometryで定義した頂点をvertexShaderに渡したが、何も表示されません
原因が特定できませんでした。shaderのエラーも特に見られませんでした。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>shader particles 01</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stats"></div>
  <div id="renderer"></div>

  <script type="importmap">
       {
         "imports" : {
           "three" : "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.0/build/three.module.js",
           "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.0/examples/jsm/"
         }
       }
     </script>

  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';

    function init() {

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 10;

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
      document.getElementById('renderer').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // 幅と高さを取得
      const fieldOfView = 75; // カメラの視野角（FOV）
      const aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; // アスペクト比
      const cameraDepth = 10; // カメラが見る範囲の奥行き
      const height_3D = Math.tan((fieldOfView * Math.PI / 180) / 2) * cameraDepth; // 高さ
      const width_3D = height_3D * aspectRatio; // 幅

      const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      // shader particles
      // vertexShader
      const vertexShader = `
      attribute vec3 particlePosition;

      float random(vec2 st) {
        return fract(sin(dot(st.xy, vec2(12.9898, 78.233)))*43758.545312);
      }

      void main() {
        gl_PointSize = 5.0;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(particlePosition, 1.0);
      }
      `;

      // fragmentShader
      const fragmentShader = `
      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      }
      `;

      // bufferGeometry
      const bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      const particleCount = 100;
      const particles = new Float32Array(particleCount * 3);
      for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i += 3) {
        particles[i] = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * width_3D;
        particles[i + 1] = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * height_3D;
        particles[i + 2] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
      }
      bufferGeometry.setAttribute('particlePosition', new THREE.BufferAttribute(particles, 3));



      const shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
        uniforms: {
          time: { value: 0 },
          resolution: { value: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight },
          initFrag: { value: 1 },
        },
      });

      const points = new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry, shaderMaterial);
      scene.add(points);


      const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
      scene.add(light);

      var stats = initStats();
      var initFrag = 1;

      render();
      function render() {
        stats.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      function initStats() {
        var stats = new Stats();
        stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
        document.getElementById("stats").appendChild(stats.domElement);
        return stats;
      }


    }

    window.onload = init;

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```